# Why checkbox just ignoring event.namespace, and fires all the bound handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, namespaces

The jQuery `.on()` and `.trigger()` methods provide a way to bind and fire multiple handlers on a single element by specifying "event.namespace", without disturbing each other.

However, I found namespace is not working for `checkbox`, it just fires all the bound handlers which are attached in different namespaces.

The code is very simple, something like:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click.n1',func1).on('click.n2',func2);

$('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click.n1');
```

Both `func1` and `func2` would be fired.
The same code works fine on other elements.

Is it a bug? Or did I miss something for checkboxes?

```js
$("#myCheckbox")
  .on('click.checks1',function(e){console.log('click.checks1 fired, the namespace is: '+e.namespace)})
  .on('click.checks2',function(e){console.log('click.checks2 fired, the namespace is: '+e.namespace)});
$("#myCheckbox").trigger('click.checks1');

$("#myRadio")
  .on('click.radios1',function(e){console.log('click.radios1 fired, the namespace is: '+e.namespace)})
  .on('click.radios2',function(e){console.log('click.radios2 fired, the namespace is: '+e.namespace)});
$("#myRadio").trigger('click.radios1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='myCheckbox' />
<input type='radio' id='myRadio' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there:

`$("#checks input")
  .on('click.checks1',function(){console.log('click.checks1')})
  .on('click.checks2',function(){console.log('click.checks2')});`

you define both events for all `#checks input`. So each time you click on 1, both are fired.

Possible duplicate of: [Custom namespaced events will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664107/custom-namespaced-events-will-not-work)

And from [there](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

> they are not hierarchical; only one name needs to match

So essentially the "click" event fire "click" event,"click.checks1" event and "click.checks2" event cause only one name needs to match.

EDIT:

As you can see in the snippet below, checkboxes call the `click` event and then this raise both events.

Radiobutton instead do not call the `click` event and call only the event with the namespace you defined.

Moreover you can see that `e.handleObj.namespace` has a value for checkboxes too.

It seems to be a bug.

```js
$("#myCheckbox").on('click', function (e) {console.warn('DEFAULT CHECKBOX')});
$("#myRadio").on('click', function (e) {console.warn('DEFAULT RADIO')});


$("#myCheckbox")
  .on('click.checks1',function(e){console.log('click.checks1 fired, the namespace is: '+e.namespace+ ' HandleObj NameSpace '+e.handleObj.namespace )})
  .on('click.checks2',function(e){console.log('click.checks2 fired, the namespace is: '+e.namespace+ ' HandleObj NameSpace '+e.handleObj.namespace)});
$("#myCheckbox").trigger('click.checks1');

$("#myRadio")
  .on('click.radios1',function(e){console.log('click.radios1 fired, the namespace is: '+e.namespace+ ' HandleObj NameSpace '+e.handleObj.namespace)})
  .on('click.radios2',function(e){console.log('click.radios2 fired, the namespace is: '+e.namespace+ ' HandleObj NameSpace '+e.handleObj.namespace)});
$("#myRadio").trigger('click.radios1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' id='myCheckbox' />
<input type='radio' id='myRadio' />
```

Comment: I define both events in two different namespaces checks1 and checks2, and I dont actually click the checkbox, instead, I use the .trriger('click.checks1') method to fire the handler attached with namespace checks1. The issue is, checkbox fires both handler, while radio button fires ONLY ONE handler as expected.

Comment: `$("#myCheckbox").trigger('click.checks3');` will trigger `click` event as well.

Comment: Yep, you explained the issue more clearly. It seems that namespaces is invalid for checkboxes.

Comment: And finally I found `$("#myCheckbox").triggerHandler('click.checks1');` will work, but there are some other defects.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong.

```
$('checkbox').on('click.n1',func1).on('click.n2',func2);
```

should be

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click.n1',func1).on('click.n2',func2);
```

Here is a small example that will make this work, though I cannot know if it will actually help you as you don't explain what you are trying to do.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('test.n1',function (e) {
    console.log(e.namespace);
});

$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e) {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('test.n1');
});
```

So this, in your existing code, will trigger the checkbox every time you click on a radio button.

More info in the official jquery api https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: the selector is for example only (I'll fix it though), you can run the code snippet below to check the problem

Comment: Thank you for your code, but I not trying to do anything between checkbox and radio button. They are used for illustrating how event.namespace work on different types of elements.